# Excel Customize Workbook with xml

Tags: xml, vba, excel

I'm trying to customize my workbook editing an xml file (CustomUi folders). I'm able to hide all menu, customize ribbon etc. Now I would like to hide "Help" button, Minimize, Restore and Close one on the top right of workbook. I tried:

```
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui"> 
    <button idMso="Help" visible="false"/> 
    <button idMso="WindowMinimize" visible="false"/>   
    <button idMso="WindowRestore" visible="false"/>  
    <button idMso="WindowClose" visible="false"/>     
</customUI>
```

But it doesn't work.
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about just using this instead to achieve what you want? No XML edits needed. These will need to go into the `ThisWorkbook` object

```
Private Sub Workbook_Activate()
    Application.ExecuteExcel4Macro "SHOW.TOOLBAR(""Ribbon"",False)"
    Application.DisplayFormulaBar = False
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = Not Application.DisplayStatusBar
    ActiveWindow.DisplayWorkbookTabs = False

End Sub
```

---

```
Private Sub Workbook_Deactivate()

    Application.ExecuteExcel4Macro "SHOW.TOOLBAR(""Ribbon"",True)"
    Application.DisplayFormulaBar = True
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
    ActiveWindow.DisplayWorkbookTabs = True

End Sub
```

Comment: hi, thank you for your answer. a nice and easy way to hide toolbar (all). but what i wold like to do is to customize my ribbon with my menu, so i need tool bar, but i want to hide just excel help button (on the right) and if it's possibile minimize, restore and close button. so my workbook appears as a stand alone interface. thank you again ;)